# Why is the cancel button in my media picker not working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmediapickercontroller

I'm a new developer and I'm getting to know music and sound in iOS.

I've managed to make a media picker where the user can select music but when I press the cancel button, nothing happens. This is the method I'm using:

```
- (void) mediaPickerDidCancel: (MPMediaPickerController *) mediaPicker
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I tried putting an NSLog in it to see if it was actually being called and there was nothing in the console so it's not actually being called at all. Is there a reason and solution that can be concluded with this information? Have I simply missed out something or might have not done something elsewhere?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

If the code I used for the media picker would be helpful, here it is:

```
MPMediaPickerController *mediaPicker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeAnyAudio];

        [mediaPicker setDelegate:self];

        mediaPicker.prompt = NSLocalizedString(@"text1", "text2");

        [self presentViewController:mediaPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: did you add the "`MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate`" declaration to your "`@implementation`" .h file?

Comment: Is 'self' being released while the media picker is presented?

Comment: Michael Dautermann: Do you mean like this? `@interface SoundViewController : UITableViewController <MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate>` If so, I've done that. Wain: I'm using ARC, would that be a problem? I don't know when 'self' is being released.

Answer (score 3):

I wonder if you need to do:

```
- (void) mediaPickerDidCancel: (MPMediaPickerController *) mediaPicker
{
    [mediaPicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

instead?

Also, set a break point within your "`mediaPickerDidCancel`" method and just see it the breakpoint even hits when hitting the cancel button in the picker.

Comment: I tried your first suggestion of changing 'self' but that made no difference. Onto your second suggestion, I know how to add a breakpoint, but I don't know how to find out if it's hit. Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: if you add a breakpoint on the "`dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES`" line, does app execution stop when you click the picker's cancel button?

Comment: No, It doesn't, it still just does nothing. The app keeps running. I don't know if this could affect anything, but I'm using it in a UITableView using a Navigation Controller. Might something be going wrong there?

Answer (score 1):

In Swift :

```
func mediaPickerDidCancel(mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController){
    // Dismiss the picker if the user canceled
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: For Swift 3 you need 
func mediaPickerDidCancel(_ mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController)